# OpenSSL enabled but Unable to find the wrapper "ssl"

Tags: php, email, ssl

We already migrated a website and we have found this error while sending email to certains domains of email addresses through function mail of PHP (hosted in the same server):

> Could not send email: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper
>   "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

On the other hand, email was successfully sent to others domains like gmail.com or hotmail.com.

**OpenSSL is enabled** and **allow_url_fopen is On**

As sender we use *sendmail* but it seems it's not correctly configured. We havve added the sender's domain to /etc/mail/local-host-names and we have added

```
define('MAIL_HUB','ourdomain.com.')dnl
define('LOCAL_RELAY','ourdomain.com.')dnl
```

at the bottom of /etc/mail/sendmail.mc (*sendmailconfig* and *service sendmail restart* executed after modification)

Environment:

- PHP 5.6.29-0deb8u1 over fastcgi
- OpenSSL 1.0.1k
- Apache 2.4.10
- Sendmail 8.14.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. The mail server is different from website server and sendmail tries to send the emails directly to website server.

I've just only added these lines to the end of */etc/mail/sendmail.mc*

```
define(`MAIL_HUB',`website.server.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY',`website.server.com.')dnl
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME',`mail.server.com')dnl
```

and run these commands

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```

and

```
service sendmail restart
```